# Entity Framework filter on foreign key

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

Depot_ID is a foreign key in the database table Address.  In my entity model i noticed that the foreign keys are not listed in the diagram

```
var Address = db.ADDRESS.Where(a => a.Depot_ID == id.Value);
```

This does not work as Depot_id is a foreign key in the Address table.  What do I need to do to filter on this field?

Comment: In the .NET 4 version of EF, this is one of the major new feature: the fact foreign key fields can be incorporated into and used in the model. So if you can: upgrade to .NET 4 - that would solve this (and many more) shortcomings and problems with EF in VS2008

Comment: I'm stuck with vs2008 for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference the ID via the navigation property. You don't say what your class properties are named, but the general idea is:

```
var Address = db.ADDRESS.Where(a => a.Depot.Depot_ID == id.Value);
```

Comment: As an aside, I'm a big fan of Joshua Slocum's books on sailing.

Comment: haha you're the first person to catch that...yes they are good books.